# How to find all instances and display in alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have a textbox which users will type or paste comma separated values such as `A123456,B123456,C123456,D123456`

These entries need to meet certain criteria, one of which is that they must be seven (7) characters in length...no more, no less.

If they enter a value that is more than seven characters, I need to display an alert telling them that they've entered a value with too many characters.

Problem is, there can be thousands of these entries and an alert that simply says that somewhere out of the thousands of entries there are one or more entries over seven characters isn't all that helpful.

I've partially solved this with the following code:

```
val = document.getElementById("Textbox1").value;
val = val.split(',');
for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
    if((val[i].length !=7) && (val[i].length !=0)){
        alert("All entries must be seven (7) characters in lenght.  Please correct the following entries:\n" + val[i]);
        return false;
    }
}
return true; 
}
```

The problem is, I can only return one incorrect entry at a time.  So the user has to correct one, run the validation again to see if there is another one, and repeat the process until they find them all.

I'd like to figure out a way to display all the incorrect entries in the alert.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't use `alert` if they can have thousands of entries. What if they have thousands of errors?

Comment: From an UI perspective, once the validation is done I'd like the page to show all the valid values in one box, and show the failing values in another text box. Then the user could clean up the few failing values and validate again. You could accomplish this by parsing the input string and building two new strings from it: one with valid values and one with failing values (both comma-delimited). After validation, put the string(s) into text boxes.

Comment: Do you want functionality similar to that of http://regexpal.com/ where errors are highlighted as you go?

Comment: @zero298 - That's not a bad idea.  I had toyed with the concept of generating an alert saying there were incorrect entries and have those bad entries highlighted in the field.  I may want to look into it...any suggestions on how to accomplish that sort of thing?

Comment: @BrettFromLA -This is also a good idea...I think someone below mentioned it too.  You're both absolutely right...having an alert box with thousands of entries is probably not the best user experience...not to mention, I seem to recall there being a limit to the length of an alert box.  I'll give it some thought.  With the code p.s.w.g. provided, I can probably mod it to work in a div or something else instead of an alert.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user2880218 yes, download the JS lib http://stevenlevithan.com/regex/colorizer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), like this:

```
var val = document.getElementById("Textbox1").value,
    err = $(val.split(',')).filter(function(){ return this.length != 7; }).toArray();
if (err.length) {
    alert("All entries must be seven (7) characters in length.  Please correct the following entries: \n" + err);
    return false; 
}
return true;
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/b9pMF/)

Or [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/), like this:

```
var val = document.getElementById("Textbox1").value,
    err = $.grep(val.split(','), function(a) { return a.length != 7; });
if (err.length) {
    alert("All entries must be seven (7) characters in length.  Please correct the following entries: \n" + err);
    return false; 
}
return true;
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/pHw8D/)

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I was looking for.  Thank you for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

On can do this :
-On change event, you check every values but the last one (which is not finished yet).
If a comma is typed and the last one is not correct, do not allow the user to keep typing and remove the comma (or it will be endless loop).

You have solved the looking-for-the-error problem.

You can also search for some kind of setCursorPosition ..

Comment: this won't work if the user enters the data with Copy - Paste

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `alert()`. Make a `<div>` like this and append all messages to it, this way the use gets all messages at once. And it's a nicer way to display errors also.

HTML:

```
<div id="alerts"></div>
```

JS:

```
var errors=""; //put HTML for error messages here
$("#alerts").append(errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily, by storing all bad entries into a variable and then getting all alert a message with all entries.

Like this one:

```
val = document.getElementById("Textbox1").value;
val = val.split(',');
    var is_Error = false;
    var ErrrMsg = "All entries must be seven (7) characters in lenght.  Please correct the following entries:\n";
    for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){    
       if((val[i].length !=7) && (val[i].length !=0)){
          ErrrMsg += val[i] +  ",";
          is_Error = true;
       }    
    }
    if(is_Error == true){
      alert(ErrrMsg.substring(0,(ErrrMsg.length - 1)));/*Here "substring" is used to remove last comma into message string.*/
      return false;
    }
    return true;
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SZRQT/2/)