# Find all instances and display alert - part 2, now with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Thanks for your help with my earlier question:

[How to find all instances and display in alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467977/how-to-find-all-instances-and-display-in-alert)

Now I discover that I need to include some invalid character validation.

I'm trying to figure out how to include a set of regex invalid characters as part of the validation that will also show up in the same alert/textbox/whatever as the "too long/too short" validation.

So, I have a textbox which users will type or paste comma separated values such as `AAAAAAA,BBBBBBB,CCCCCCCC,DDDDDDDD`

And they cannot be more or less than seven characters long and they can only include certain characters.

I currently have have two separate pieces of Javascript that I'm trying to now combine:

```
var Invalidchars = "1234567890!@#$%^&*()+=[]\\\';./{}|\":<>?";
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("TextBox1").value.length; i++) {
   if (Invalidchars.indexOf(document.getElementById("TextBox").value.charAt(i)) != -1){
   alert
```

and this

```
var val = document.getElementById("Textbox1").value,
    err = $.grep(val.split(','), function(a) { return a.length != 7; });
if (err.length) {
    alert("All entries must be seven (7) characters in length.  Please correct the following entries: \n" + err);
    return false; 
}
return true;
```

Any help is much appreciated!

=================================================

SOLUTION
Took a while, but using Tenub's code (which didn't quite combine my two sets code, but was close enough), I finally figured out how to merge my two sets of code into one.  Here's the code if anyone is ever interested in using it:

```
var val = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value,
    err = $.grep(val.split(','), function(a) {return (a.length = (!/^[^0-9!@#$%^&*()+=;.\/\{}|:<>\\?\[\]\'\"]{7}$/.test(a)));});
if (err.length){   
    document.getElementById("DIV1").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = err.join(',');
        return callback (false);
    }
document.getElementById("DIV1").style.display = "none";
return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as simple as it is elegant:

```
var val = document.getElementById("Textbox1").value;
if(!/[^0-9!@#$%^&*()+=;./{}|:<>?\[\]\\\'\"]{7}/.test(val)) {
    // handle invalid value
}
```

This tests that the string is 7 characters in length and does *not* contain any character within the brackets after the "^" (also some characters are escaped with a "\").

You can test in console:

```
/[^0-9!@#$%^&*()+=;./{}|:<>?\[\]\\\'\"]{7}/.test('adfFDKZ'); // returns true
/[^0-9!@#$%^&*()+=;./{}|:<>?\[\]\\\'\"]{7}/.test('adf(DKZ'); // returns false
```

Comment: What I need is to combine the two sets of code I provided.  Meaning, I need to validate a textbox with CSV for both length and invalid characters and any value that is not the correct length and/or has invalid characters should throw generate an error with a list of all the incorrectly entered values.

Comment: I forgot about the {n} syntax... Thanks for the (unintentional) reminder!

Comment: I would like to mention that it doesn't split the CSV up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* 
 * This regex matches all the invalid characters. I escaped the
 * special characters.
 */
var regex = /.*[0-9!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\+=\[\]\\';\./\{\}\|":\<\>\?]+.*/;

var text = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;

/* Test for match...much faster than a for-loop under any circumstances */
if (text.matches(regex)) {
  alert("Invalid characters present. Please correct the input");
  return false;
}

/* split on delimiter */
var err = $.grep(val.split(','), function(a) { return a.length != 7; });
if (err.length) {
  alert("All entries must be seven (7) characters in length.  Please correct the following entries: \n" + err);
  return false;
}
```

Please tell me if there are any bugs in this. Also, the only real way to test for this in one step is to set up an enormously long regex. Also, with only one check, it would make it a little harder to guide the user to make the right correction. I will mention that.

Comment: I may be missing something, but this appears to be nearly the same code I entered...just done a bit different.  I don't see how this combines the two concepts.  Meaning, I need to validate a textbox with CSV for both length and invalid characters and any value that is not the correct length and/or has invalid characters should throw generate an error with a list of all the incorrectly entered values.

Comment: Ok. The above answer reminded me of syntax that I failed to remember (or I would have used that and trimmed a lot of code).